# How to update system firmware on MSI machines?

Tags: updates, executable, firmware, msi

**MSI** machines support just a single method for updating the firmware, and that is through .exe files released by MSI.

Since **MSI** officially supports just the Windows operating system, all there support and services are centred around it.

Is there any known procedure for updating the firmware on an MSI machine running Linux (esp. Ubuntu)?

I don't think trying to run the updated firmware .exe file through **Wine** or **PlayOnLinux** would be a safe thing to do!

Can it be done through a virtual machine running on my Ubuntu?

Comment: The two reasons I keep Windows on my dual-boot machines are for 1) BIOS and Firmware updates and 2) Gaming.

Comment: Perhaps that's some kind of answer although I don't have any experience in using this software https://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom Thus please read more before using.

Answer (score 0):

This website says that you load firmware onto a USB stick and then reboot.

https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/2772-how-to-update-bios-with-m-flash-msi-motherboards

Quoting them...

### Setup & Necessary Tools

Motherboard with simple firmware flashing tools
USB storage device
The most recent version of the motherboard’s BIOS, found on the motherboard vendor’s website. Place this onto the USB key.

### Step-by-Step Guide to Updating BIOS on an MSI Motherboard

It’s very easy, really:

- Navigate to the motherboard vendor’s website (MSI, in this case) and find the exact board you’re using. Don’t settle for “close enough” – find the exact product.
- Go to Support, then download the latest BIOS that’s relevant to you.
- Boot to BIOS and navigate System Information to find the current BIOS version. Make a note in case you need to roll-back.
- Navigate to M-Flash.
- Select the USB device, then the file, then proceed.
- Accept the prompt after review and allow the flash to continue.
- DO NOT INTERRUPT THIS PROCESS. If it looks like there is no progress, be patient and walk away from it. Restarting now can damage something.
- Re-apply BIOS settings that you like.

Comment: Thank you for responding, @RonJohn, but these steps are for updating the BIOS, not the system firmware. These are two entirely different things!

Comment: @AbbasMehdi the BIOS is stored in firmware, making them **exactly** the same thing.  If you think I'm wrong, present some evidence.

Comment: The simplest evidence is the fact that many manufacturers (including MSI) offer two different files for the respective updates/upgrades. Simply visit any product page to find more details. This is mine: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GV62-7RD

Comment: @AbbasMehdi firmware is just software stored in nonvolatile memory.  Since before 1981, the BIOS has been stored on the motherboard in firmware.

Comment: then it does not make sense to issue two separate files for updating/upgrading BIOS and firmware, along with their respective update/upgrade procedures, since updating/upgrading the firmware would automatically update/upgrade the BIOS as well (since it's a part of firmware, as you propose)!

Comment: @AbbasMehdi the PC BIOS is a form of firmware.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS "**BIOS** (pronounced: /ˈbaɪɒs/, BY-oss; an acronym for Basic Input/Output System and also known as the System BIOS, ROM BIOS or PC BIOS) **is firmware** used to perform hardware initialization during the booting process (power-on startup), and to provide runtime services for operating systems and programs.[1] The **BIOS firmware** comes pre-installed on a personal computer's system board, and it is the first software to run when powered on."

Comment: Oh Dear! I know what a BIOS is and what a firmware is, by God's grace. I know that the BIOS is getting obsolete and has already been replaced by (U)EFI in most of the computers out there. I know what they both stand for, as well as what they mean and what they do, as I myself am an embedded engineer. I not at all referred to their absolute definitions anywhere in this thread, rather was referring in context of MSI and some other systems.

Comment: Just tell me why MSI issues two separate files for updating/upgrading BIOS and firmware, along with their respective update/upgrade procedures!

Comment: @AbbasMehdi you're still ignoring the fact that firmware is just software that "live" in nonvolatile memory.  Windows can be burned into firmware, for God's sake. Quite frequently, MS-DOS was burned into firmware to run cash registers and other POS terminals.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are far far away from the question here!

Comment: @AbbasMehdi if you weren't the one who asked the original question, I'd think you were trolling me.

Comment: Oh Dear.  RonJohn is correct but is being pedantic.  The BIOS is Firmware.  
MSI is providing two separate files - one for BIOS and one for EC Firmware.  Most Likely, you only need a bios update. EC Firmware deals with other embedded parts of the motherboard like ethernet or sdcard or webcam.  Bios codes the basic boot operation and the bios menu and is first to execute.  EC Firmware follows when you want to use your webcam or something else.

Comment: The bios and EC firmware write to different chips. I am not sure that the bios flash utility in the uefi settings is capable of writing to ec, I would be afraid that flashing the ec firmware to the bios chip would brick the bios/mb.  The bios flash has to happen on our msi boards without the OS running afaik, and the less critical chips for the EC (lan, sd, usb, hdmi, sound, processor states, cooling, etc chips) can be flashed with the system running.